# Admob + Andengine showing ad only on second request

Tags: android, admob, andengine

the issue is: the ad doesn't show on first request, but when it makes the second request, it shows right. About 2 seconds before it make the second request, the ad of the first request shows up. Any ideas?
Thanks,

**EDIT:** I changed the gravity to TOP, and now it shows on the first time, but is showing just the top half of the ad, bizarre, any ideas?

```
@Override
protected void onSetContentView() {

    if(adView != null){
        return;
    }

    final FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(this);
    final FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameLayoutLayoutParams =
            new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                         FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    final FrameLayout.LayoutParams adViewLayoutParams =
            new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                         FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                         Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL|Gravity.BOTTOM);

    adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId(getResources().getString(R.string.ad_unit_id));
    adView.setAdListener(new ToastAdListener(this));
    adView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

    this.mRenderSurfaceView = new RenderSurfaceView(this);
    mRenderSurfaceView.setRenderer(mEngine,this);

    final android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams surfaceViewLayoutParams =
            new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(super.createSurfaceViewLayoutParams());

    frameLayout.addView(this.mRenderSurfaceView, surfaceViewLayoutParams);
    frameLayout.addView(adView, adViewLayoutParams);

    this.setContentView(frameLayout, frameLayoutLayoutParams);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    if(adView!=null){
        adView.pause();
    }
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(adView!=null){
        adView.resume();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if(adView!=null){
        adView.destroy();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: also, when I click any button or the back button, before the activity exit, the ad shows correctly

Answer (score 2):

The problem was solved for me by adding the line
adView.setBackgroundColor(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT);

Answer (score 1):

The way I have done is as follows:

1. In the method which changes the visibility, I first check is the ad was loaded. If it was not, I don't change the visibility
2. Set an `AdListener` for the `AdView`. in the `onReceivedAd()`, I check the condition to hide it - if it should be hidden, I hide.

Works fine this way.

Comment: I want it to be always visible. I set the adListener and when the activity runs, I see a toast triggered by onAdLoaded(), so it is loading correctly, but it doesn't show the first time for some reason.
I don't change the visibility because it is visible by default, right?

Comment: debugging I saw that it is always visible, always in the correct position, and on the onAdLoaded() I force to refresh calling adView.refreshDrawableState(), still doesn't work, just after 1 minute when it calls the request again :(

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same problem, I solved this way:

Advertisement class:

```
public class Advertisement {

    private AdView adView;
    private final Handler adsHandler = new Handler();

    public Advertisement(final Activity activity) {
    adView = (AdView)activity.findViewById(R.id.adView);        
    }

    //show the ads.
    private void showAds () {
        adView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        adView.setVisibility(android.view.View.VISIBLE);
        adView.setEnabled(true);
    }

    //hide ads.
    private void unshowAds () {
        adView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        adView.setVisibility(android.view.View.INVISIBLE);
        adView.setEnabled(false);
    }

    final Runnable unshowAdsRunnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            unshowAds();
        }
    };

    final Runnable showAdsRunnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            showAds();
        }
    };

    public void showAdvertisement() {
        adsHandler.post(showAdsRunnable);
    }

    public void hideAdvertisement() {
        adsHandler.post(unshowAdsRunnable);
    }
}
```

In code:

```
...
public static Advertisement advertisement = new Advertisement(this);
...
public static void showAd() 
{
    if (advertisement != null) 
        advertisement.showAdvertisement();
}
public static void hideAd() 
{
    if (gangsterAdvertisement != null) 
        advertisement.hideAdvertisement();
}
```

Comment: How i can use this class ?
It shows me all times this error during compile

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo